# Embed video in web page

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am working in asp.net MVC. I want to add video files in web page. Mostly file formats are           `flv` and `mp4` which I have to use. I have tried the following

```
<video src="myvideo.mp4"><video> which works well in Chrome but not in Firefox.
```

Then i tried ASP.NET Video Helper

```
@Video.Flash(path: "myvideo.mp4",
                 width: "400",
                 height: "600",
                 play: true,
                 loop: true,
                 menu:  false,
                 bgColor: "red",
                 quality: "medium",
                 scale: "exactfit",
                 windowMode: "transparent")
```

And

```
@Video.MediaPlayer(
        path: "myvideo.mp4",
        width: "400",
        height: "600",
        autoStart: true,
        playCount: 2,
        uiMode:  "full",
        stretchToFit: true,
        enableContextMenu: true,
        mute: false,
        volume: 75)
```

And

```
@Video.Silverlight(
        path: "myvideo.mp4",
        width: "400",
        height: "600",
        bgColor: "red",
        autoUpgrade: true)
```

But nothing is working. I have already installed `Web Helper Library`. Only error message i get in each of these browsers is: "`Plugin Missing`". When i click "Search missing plugin automatically", then browser shows message "no plugin found". Please guide me how can i add videos (mp4 and flv) to my web page, so that it may work everywhere. Help please.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Firefox doesn't support MP4. When I hosted movies on website I used `<video>` as you, but a provide it in two formats: MP4 for IE and Safari and WEBM for others.

```
<video poster="movie.jpg" controls>
    <source src="movie.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8.0, vorbis"'/>
    <source src="movie.ogg" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'/>
    <source src="movie.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4D401E, mp4a.40.2"'/>
    <p>This is fallback content</p>
</video>
```

You can read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video) about video tag and format supported on various browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI - The firefox version that just went live yesterday now supports h.264, so this shouldn't be a problem for any updated versions of firefox anymore.